# Symbols in Windows 7 (e.g. PowerPoint, Word)

Tags: windows, fonts, ms-word, powerpoint, symbols

I've got a little problem with symbols in Power Point. On PC A (Win 7) I am using a professional Version of Powert Point to create my slides.

On PC B (also Win 7) I am only using the Power Point Viewer.

It seems that PC B does not have got the fonts and symbols I am using on PC A. To copy the font was not a problem. It works fine.

But how can I copy the symbols from PC A to PC B? Right now, PC B takes a standard symbol for List items (looks like a rectangle, but in original it is a circle)

Or is there a way to embedd symbols into my slides, so that PC B takes it from the ppt-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a question for SuperUser, as it doesn't apparently have anything to do with coding.  You need to embed the fonts you've used.  Since you don't mention the version you're using, I'll assume the current one, 2010.

File | Save As
On the Save As dialog box, click the down arrow on the Tools button
In the resulting Options dialog box, put a check next to "Embed fonts in the file"
Then go ahead and save.

Some fonts are embeddable, some are not.